# How can I display the numbers from 1 to 10 and in reverse 10 to 1 using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have written below code and I got *1 to 10 numbers* but it is not displaying reverse *from 10 to 1*.

Below is my `Javascript` code.

```js
function reverse() {
  for (var n = 0; n < 10;) {
    n++;
    console.log(n);
  }
  if (reverse) {
    console.log(n);
  } else {
    console.log(n);
  }
}

console.log(reverse(1234567891010987654321));
```

Comment: Your program is totally wrong. I can see at least 5 big problems in it

Comment: lol what did you want exactly ... ?

Comment: I want to use one for loop and one if condition

Comment: Why is there a parameter in the call ? Why is there a undefined boolean ? What is this for loop with N++ inside ?

Comment: What a crap is this?

Comment: And people still answering this question just for reputation points :(... How sad

Comment: I am getting the answer for 1 to 10.. And i want to get in reverse 10 to 1 using if condition.

Comment: @RickBronger Thats because he is not returning anything from function.

Comment: can u please tell me what iam not returning in the function

Comment: i have to use if condition in that code and i used to get 10 to 1 in reverse

Comment: And iam getting for 1 to 10 and there is a wrong in the if condition

Comment: @RickBronger I just formatted code. Did not add a single extra letter.

Comment: @balajiunnam Why dont you look at the answers ?

Comment: @balajiunnam In `console.log(reverse(1234567891010987654321));`, you are logging output of `reverse`. Inside reverse, you are not returning anything, so it logs `undefined`

Comment: Thats not the matter dude but i want to print in reverse using if condition and with out using two for loops

Answer (score 2):

You could use one loop and increment, but make a correction for the output.

```js
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    console.log(i > 10 ? 20 - i : i);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With double 10

```js
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    console.log(i > 10 ? 21 - i : i);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice one but what if he needs to display 2 times `10` ? :)

Answer (score 1):

This code will display from  to 10 then from 10 to 1

```js
var toDisplay = "";
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
  toDisplay+=i;  
}
for(var j=10; j>=1; j--){
  toDisplay+=j; 
}

console.log(toDisplay);
```

Answer (score 1):

Exists [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) function too:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

console.log(array);
console.log(array.reverse());
```

Answer (score 1):

To print any input in reverse, use a for loop:

```
   function printReverse(arr){
        //looping through the array backwards and console.log each item
        for(var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            console.log(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    printReverse([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
```

Answer (score 0):

just flip the "<"  operator

```
if(!reverse){ //If reverse boolean is false

     //Forward
     for(var n = 1; n <= 10) { console.log(n) } 

 } else { // reverse is true

     //Backwards
     for(var n = 10; n >= 1) { console.log(n) } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

simply do like this

```
var V;
for (V = 1; V < 20; V++) {
    console.log(V > 10 ? 20 - V : V);
}
```

Comment: nice idea. ;)))